# Using AsParallel on an IEnumerable - Will it have any benefit of parallelism at all?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

```
IEnumerable<char> GetChars()
        {
            int i = int.MinValue;
            while (i++ < int.MaxValue)
            {
                yield return (char)('A' + (i % 26));
            }
        }
```

Is there any benefit of applying `AsParallel` to above character enumerable?

`GetChars().AsParallel().REST_OF_THE_QUERY`

Because, from my knowledge for this to work in parallel on many threads, there needs to be partition of the data for different threads available in parallel. But here I think the enumerator will be a bottleneck because it can not run in parallel?

Will `AsParallel` be able to fetch data in parallel from this enumerator and utilize the benefit of multithreading?

Comment: @GSerg will AsParallel impact original GetChar function, I think it wouldn't, because there is no enumerable to be partitioned yet, the partition will happen once GetChars result is returned and the next enumerator called, am I right ?

Comment: @Munzer No, the function is an enumerator, it does not return the result, it returns an enumerator that will start producing results when you start enumerating it.

Comment: @GSerg it is confusing to me, because the doc reads `The AsParallel extension method binds the subsequent query operators, in this case ....`. and this was appended in their example to an enumerator function which Enumerable.Range().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the query:

```
GetChars().AsParallel().REST_OF_THE_QUERY
```

The `REST_OF_THE_QUERY` will be parallelized. The `GetChars` will not be parallelized<del>, and will run exclusively in the current thread</del>. The `AsParallel` parallelizes what follows it (as long as each subsequent operator returns a [`ParallelQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelquery-1)). It doesn't parallelize what precedes it.

---

**Update:** [GSerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11683) pointed out in the comments that with `GetChars().AsParallel()` the current thread ID keeps changing inside `GetChars`, although it appears to be some locking involved, as no two threads enter `GetChars` at the same time. My experiments matched these observations. This means that the PLINQ library cannot be used for querying a data source that requires thread affinity. For example the code below throws an exception in WinForms:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;
    int count = GetHandles().AsParallel().Count();
    MessageBox.Show($"Controls: {count}");
}

private IEnumerable<IntPtr> GetHandles()
{
    foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        yield return control.Handle;
    }
}
```

> InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Button1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Without `.AsParallel()`, no exception is thrown.

Comment: A simple experiment shows that with `GetChars().AsParallel()` `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` keeps changing inside `GetChars`, and that the calls into `GetChars` to get a new element are interlined with execution of the respective `REST_OF_THE_QUERY` for already fetched elements. However there does appear to be some locking involved, as it would appear that no two threads enter `GetChars` at the same time.

Comment: @GSerg you are right. I should have tested it before answering!